# C# overload key/value and non key/value type , using var without specifying type

Tags: c#

Below example when `explicitly specify type` will call `Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>`,`var` keword `call Execute<T>`

I trying slove the problem,because user alway use `var v = "";` not `string v = ""`

EX:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> data = new[] {
        new Dictionary<string, string> (){
            {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
        }
    };
    data.Execute(); //call Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums){}

    var data2 = new[] {
        new Dictionary<string, string> (){
            {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
        }
    };
    data2.Execute(); //call Execute<T>
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums){}

    public static void Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums){
    }
}
```

I tried to slove the problem by `is`.

When key/value is `<object,object>` the value `enums is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>>` is `true`,but the key/value is `<string,string>` will return `false`.

I hope no matter what is key/value's type , `enums is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>>` always get `true`.

```
void Main()
{
    var dataBy_String_String = new[] {
        new Dictionary<string, string> (){
            {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
        }
    };
    dataBy_String_String.Execute(); //ExecuteByNonKeyValueType

    var dataBy_Object_Object = new[] {
        new Dictionary<object, object> (){
            {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
        }
    };
    dataBy_Object_Object.Execute(); //ExecuteByKeyValueType 
}

public static class Test
{
    private static void ExecuteByKeyValueType<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums) { }
    private static void ExecuteByNonKeyValueType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums) { }

    public static void Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums){
        if(enums is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>>){
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteByKeyValueType");
            ExecuteByKeyValueType(enums as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>>);
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteByNonKeyValueType");
            ExecuteByNonKeyValueType(enums);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ex. user alway use `var v = "";` not `string v = ""`

Comment: yes,I want to distinguish between non Key/Value Type and Key/Value Type

Comment: If this is a major concern, I'd call the two methods different names.

Comment: @mjwills  thanks,it's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, either force your team to use the correct types, for example by using [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Using_var_Keyword_in_Declarations.html) which can show a warning or error if you use `var`, or tell them that they should at least specify the argument types:

```
var data = new[] {
    new Dictionary<string, string> (){
        {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
    }
};

// calls wrong overload
data.Execute(); //calls IEnumerable<T>
// calls corrrect
data.Execute<string, string>(); //calls IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>
```

---

```
public static void Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>");
}

public static void Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable<T>");
}
```

Another solution was to provide a third, more specific overload for your dictionaries, which does the cast and calls the desired overload:

```
public static void Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> dictionaries)
{
    var enums = (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>) dictionaries;
    enums.Execute();
}
```

Now your team members can use `var` and don't need to specify the type arguments.

Comment: it's a solution, if no another answer i'll accept it, thanks @Rango , I also trying slove without `Execute<string,string>`.